# Select postgresql within 1 hour range of current date

Tags: postgresql

**GOAL**

I have a table which is fed by a collection of an agent [ZABBIX](https://www.zabbix.com/), with a   TIMEOUT of 3 seconds.

I would like to do a`SELECT` within a range of **1 hour in 1 hour** always from the current date of the execution of `SELECT`, the query below does not report any errors, but does not bring any information.

**SQL**

```
 SELECT
     *
 FROM
     history
 WHERE
     "clock"> = now () - interval '60 minutes';
```

**DATE**

```
 2019-10-28 08:10:00.424430
 2019-10-28 08:11:03.424523
 2019-10-28 08:12:06.424596
 ...
 2019-10-28 09:10:00.424430
 2019-10-28 09:11:03.424523
 2019-10-28 09:12:06.424596
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
 2019-10-28 08:00:03.424439
 2019-10-28 09:00:03.424522
 2019-10-28 10:00:03.424591
```

**NOTE:** The `clock` column of the`history` table is **TIMESTAMP**

Comment: `08:00:03.424439` (from the first row of the desired output) does not seem to be contained in the sample data - where does that time come from?

Comment: From a zabbix monitoring agent INSERT

Comment: But your sample input data doesn't contain that value. What is the logic that includes that value in the output?

Comment: The output values are illustrative, I may have wrongly exemplified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need something like

```
SELECT MIN(clock)
FROM history
WHERE date_trunc('day', clock) = CURRENT_DATE
/* or WHERE clock >= CURRENT_DATE */
GROUP BY date_trunc('hour', clock)
```

?

Comment: Perfect, thanks!!